# Parsing an email subject header

Tags: go, encoding, mime

I'm using `net/mail` to read email messages with Go:

```
msg, _ := mail.ReadMessage(f)
subject := msg.Header.Get("Subject")
fmt.Printf("Subject = %v", subject)
```

And I'm having trouble figuring out how to decode the subject when it has special characters and the mail provider converts it from plain text into encoded text.

For example, if an email is sent with "It’s a test" -- note that's a right curly quote -- then that subject ultimately gets UTF-8 encoded, I think with hex values, into this:

`=?UTF-8?Q?It=E2=80=99s_a_test?=`

My questions are:

1. What's the correct terminology to use for describing the encoding that's going on here?
2. What library would I uses to decode that string above (`=?UTF-8?Q?It=E2=80=99s_a_test?=`) back into `It’s a test` before doing what I need to do with it (display it, put it in a database, etc)

Comment: Your question has little to do with Go but a lot with the RFCs dealing with emails.

Comment: (I've removed the `utf-8` tag (and replaced it with `mime`) as the real encoding of the subject is the so-called "Q-encoding" (there's also "B-encoding"); that "UTF-8" bit of the format define according to which encoding actual bytes should be interpreted after having been decoded from that Q- or B-encoding.)

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer by searching `golang =?UTF-8?Q?` and seeing the functions available in Go's `mime` package

https://golang.org/pkg/mime/#WordDecoder.DecodeHeader